# Redirecting to a web site depending on date choice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have inserted a date picker on my webpage. I want a user to select a date and depending on their choice be able to go to a certain page.

I think I'll have to set variables like `day1 = <a href:http//www.yahoo.com>`.

What I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ showOtherMonths: false });
});


$('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
    { 
        window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com' + dateText;
    }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you know the dates you want to check for, you can just use an if statement:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
{ 
    //this will show a message box showing you the date format. just remove this line after.
    alert(dataText);  
    if(dateText == "some-day-1") window.location = "link to some page";
    if(dateText == "some-day-2") window.location = "link to another page";
    if(dateText == "some-day-3") window.location = "link to yet another page";
});
```

Comment: if(dateText == "15/03/2013") window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com"; Im not sure how to format for dateText, so that its the same on selection by user. so far no trigger.

Comment: just console.log(dateText) so you know the format

Comment: $("#datepicker").datepicker({ showOtherMonths: false });
     
     console.log(dateText)
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        
    inst.selectedDay = dataText
    inst.selectedMonth = dataText
    inst.selectedYear = dataText
}

     if(dateText == "15,03,2013") window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com";

Comment: could that work?, clueless on java

Comment: javascript*, and i'll edit my answer so you know what i mean. I'll use alert instead, since you might not know how to open up the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
   callFunction(this.val);
  }
});


function callFunction(value)
{
 window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com' + value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you can write down below code to checkout want the onSelect first of all, you can write down below code to checkout want the onSelect event will be trigger with in console:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

And I'm not sure want do you actually want, what's i can tell you is, the dateText will be a formated text of the use choose, and you can get the number of the day/month/year by

```
inst.selectedDay
inst.selectedMonth
inst.selectedYear
```